# Openquery alternatives? IT won't enable Openquery on new server

Tags: sql, upgrade, openquery, adhoc-queries

Is anyone aware of alternative methods of querying against Access/DB2 tables as a user in SQL Management Studio without using the Openquery syntax? My department's SQL Server is being upgraded from 2005 to 2012, and in the process, IT has stated that they will not enable openquery as it is no longer the company preferred method to call data from the multiple system tables here that are stored in Microsoft Access. The kicker - the IT project lead does not have an alternative method for us to use. Some of these tables are just too large to replicate into our SQL server.

I'm at a loss. I've searched around with little luck. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already answered I believe.

See this: [Best tool to edit/view SQL Server 2008 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554335/best-tool-to-edit-view-sql-server-2008-database)

If you are no longer allowed to use SSMS, you could view the data directly from Ms Access.

There's also a third party app in the post.

Hope this helps

Comment: I still use SSMS for querying. It's just the link to our system tables - which are held in Microsoft Access - is being cut off.